# post to twitter with clickable media

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

Currently I am posting a tweet with image from my iOS app using statuses/update_with_media twitter API, it is working fine, but I want to redirect to my app when user click on that posted tweet's image. So in short I want to embed something like url scheme to that image so that when user click on that image(by using his twitter app) then my app should open.
Please suggest me the ways to implement that, thanks in advance.

currently I am using following code to post tweet with image. I am using STTwitterAPI framework for twitter integration.

```
NSMutableArray *mediaArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
if(image)
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [mediaArray addObject:imageData];

    //share from device twitter
[api.twitter postStatusUpdate:text mediaDataArray:mediaArray possiblySensitive:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false] inReplyToStatusID:nil latitude:nil longitude:nil placeID:nil displayCoordinates:nil uploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

} successBlock:^(NSDictionary *status) {
    NSLog(@"tweet shared successfully");
    [self showActivityIndicator:2.0f];

} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"tweet share - error %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that.  Twitter images only point to the images - not elsewhere.

You could, however, try linking to a site which uses [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards).  That could display an image and link it through to wherever you wanted.